# How do I repeat JQuery Counter when timer finished

Tags: jquery, counter

I have found a great counter script but on one of the scripts I need it to repeat after the counting has reached 999. What would I add to make it repeat when finished counting?

```
        jQuery_2_2_4('#count-five').jQuerySimpleCounter({
            start : 0,
            end : 999,
            // easing effect
             easing : 'linear',
            // duration time in ms
            duration : 100000 
        });
```

Comment: put this in some function and call the function again after 999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter plugin exposes a `complete` callback. If you want it to repeat, run the same commands in the complete function. Here's one way to do it:

```
function repeatCounter() {
    jQuery_2_2_4('#count-five').jQuerySimpleCounter({
        start : 0,
        end : 999,
        // easing effect
        easing : 'linear',
        // duration time in ms
        duration : 100000,
        complete: repeatCounter
    });
}

repeatCounter();
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!